# Android web browser not writing cookie in desktop view

Tags: android, jquery, wordpress, cookies, responsiveness

Okay, so I am using a cookie to generate mobile content on different device widths. Basically the site looks one way on desktop and reveals post content on the mobile under 800px.

Everything is working perfectly except for one little issue. When I switch to desktop view in a mobile browser, seems to only be happening in iOS safari and android HTC Internet, the cookie is not being applied to the content isnt being generated. Ive tried numerous searches and suggestions across the web and havent found anything. Any help would be amazing.

Script in header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 800px)")
if (mql.matches){ var setCookie = function setCookie(name) {
document.cookie = 'distanceMobile=1; expires=0; path=/';
}
setCookie('distanceMobile');}
else{
// do something else
}</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 801px)")
if (mql.matches){    var delete_cookie = function delete_cookie(name) {
  document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
    delete_cookie('distanceMobile');}
else{
// do something else
}
</script>
```

Php for the template:

```
<?php
// Template Name: Full Width Home
get_header("home");

if ( wp_is_mobile($_COOKIE['distanceMobile']) ) {

    echo '<style scoped> @media screen and (min-width: 801px){
    #content {display: none !important;}
    }</style>';
    get_template_part('custom-home-content');
    //echo "Hello!";

} elseif ($_COOKIE['distanceMobile']) { 

    get_template_part('custom-home-content');
    //echo "Hello!";

} else {
  // do nada
}

get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is a link to the site im working on. If you shrink your browser window below 800 you will have to give 2 quick refreshes for it to print the content. Otherwise visiting on a device it will just load fine.

Again ive tried multiple things so far. I tried stripping away everything matchMedia and ive tried doing an alert. It seems to just not be working in the mobile browser when you click desktop view.

Regards.

*** Update PHP file to test if mobile is recognized and cookie firing***
Im returning the SPM in desktop view in the mobile browser

```
<?php
// Template Name: Full Width Home
get_header("home");if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {    
    get_template_part('custom-home-content');
   //echo "Hello!";
} 
    elseif ($_COOKIE['distanceMobile']) {    
        get_template_part('custom-home-content');
   //echo "Hello!";
    } 
        else {
 echo "SPM JR.";
}
get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Forgot the link, sorry, http://www.distancecme.com/home-test/

Comment: Also the 2 phones ive tested on are HTC One (M7) and iPhone 5 s